# rails create custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, controller

i created a small rails application for learning which has 3 models :

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base      
     has_many :resources
     has_many :tasks, :through=>:recources
end


class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through=>:resources

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resources,:comments 

end
```

---

everything is ok - listing,creating etc. But i wanna make a view which user upload a text file that contains tasks (it is not important how i can read text file) so i read the file and fetch the tasks. I created a controller which name is upload :

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def upload
    flash[:notice]="Upload completed"
  end

end
```

and index view like this :

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
   <p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>

<div class="upload">
  <p>Select a project file</p>
  <%= form_tag :controller=>:upload,:action => :upload,:method => :put do %>

  <%= file_field 'Project File',:file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

when i press upload button it gives me "Missing template upload/uploa...."

How can i accomplish this action, give me advice plz.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every action tries to render a template with the same name as itself if you don't specifically tell it what to `render` or `redirect_to`.  So what you can do is this:

```
     render :nothing => true
```

That should do what you want.

Also, the documentation is decent with regard to what you can do with [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Answer (score 1):

Missing template upload/uploa...."

Rails is looking for a view: app/views/upload/upload.html.erb

PS. You'll need to add in :multipart => true in your form_for to upload a file ;)